# How I can modify InternalsVisibleTo in assembly using Reflexii?

Tags: .net, reflector, internalsvisibleto, reflexil

I would to modify InternalsVisibleTo attribute value in assembly? In Reflector I see [assembly: InternalsVisibleTo(AssemblyName)] but I don't see AssemblyInfo.cs which I can modify. If it possible I'd like to change AssemblyName in the attribute to name of my native assembly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can't do it. First the value of the attribute is constant, so it couldn't be changed via reflection. Second you cant change attributes of a assembly.